# Как самым простым способом передать объект из MongoDB в Angular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, angular

В интернете просмотрел уже кучу всего и про Angular, и про NodeJS с Express, и про MongoDB, но вот как объединить их вместе без танцев с бубном не могу отыскать. Я просто хочу передать один обычный объект в Mongo и иметь возможность его считать. Как можно это сделать? Или подскажите хорошую статью на эту тему, пожалуйста.

Comment: ну наверное создать роут на стороне ноды и отдать объект респонсом? :D

Comment: подробнее можно, пожалуйста?

Comment: что именно подробнее? ты же сказал что прочитал кучу всего про express/mongo